# Displaying a proprietary logo modified to match website style

Tags: website-design, logo, copyright, legal

I'm designing a blog that has a "Tags" page.
I was thinking of displaying a modified logo for each tag.

For example:
 Tag: CocaCola Logo: CocaCola logo modified

How legal is this approach?

Comment: @Vincent, thanks. I missed that when I searched. I think it answers my question.

Comment: Great, glad I could help. In that case, I'll nominate your question to be closed as a duplicate of that one. By the way: welcome to Graphic Design SE and thanks for your question! If you want to know more about the site, please see the [help] or ping one of us in the [chat] once your reputation is sufficient (20). Keep contributing and enjoy the site!

Comment: Branding is branding and simply because you *want* something to appear in some way to match other items, that does *not* mean it's okay to modify branding. The **entire point** of branding it for it to remain *consistent* across marketing materials. Branding should **always** stay the same.... the *other items* need to change.